# Previous value and complex formula

Tags: sql

```
Interface |value |  date-time   |
-------------------------------
First-IN  |80004 |05/05/2016:12:00
First-IN  |90005 |05/05/2016:11:00
First-IN  |70005 |05/05/2016:10:00
First-IN  |90005 |05/05/2016:09:00
First-Out |30002 |05/05/2016:12:00
First-Out |40002 |05/05/2016:11:00
First-Out |20002 |05/05/2016:10:00
First-Out |10002 |05/05/2016:09:00
```

I need to sum up all values but under these conditions:

If previous value > current(next) (every second line row from top down you could consider as current) value then add 400000 to current value -(minus) previous value and that resultset as a next value.
Then continue like that.

The reason I need to add 400000 is that this counter roles over after 400000 and starts from 0.

The formula that I need to use is as follows:

```
(delata IN - delta out)*8
______________________________
   delta seconds *30
```

Would it be possible to implement this in SQL query or report builder?
Thanks to all in advance for help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow and thanks for taking the time to describe your problem and provide some example data.  It is important to tag your database platform you are using (sql-server, oralce, mysql etc.?) so we can suggest the right solution.  Also while I think I understand your description if you could include your desired result based on the example data it will like clear things up for myself and others.  Cheers

Comment: Check out the `lag()` function